# Soundcloud Widget not functioning suddenly (after 6 years)

Tags: javascript, jsonp, mime-types, soundcloud, x-content-type-options

Soundcloud audio Widget on our site stopped working last week. 
(example [here](https://puremagnetik.com/products/malletpak-vibraphone-ableton-live-pack-kontakt-instrument-apple-logic-samples)). It has been working for 6 years.

The JS console in Chrome and Safari give the following error:

> Refused to execute https://api.soundcloud.com/resolve?url=https://soundcloud.com/puremagnetik/puremagnetik-opus&format=json&consumer_key=htuiRd1JP11Ww0X72T1C3g&callback=jQuery31108344418007576904_1578931070539&_=1578931070540 as script because "X-Content-Type: nosniff" was given and its Content-Type is not a script MIME type.

Does anyone know what this could mean? Seems like it's on the Soundcloud end, yes?

Comment: Yes, this would appear to be a Soundcloud configuration issue. I would suggest reading their documentation as it's likely they have changed the implementation over the last 6 years. Without any more detail there's not much we can do to help you

Comment: Browser could've gotten more strict in some respect, as well.

Comment: The cause: `https://api.soundcloud.com/` is serving `https://api.soundcloud.com/resolve?callback=` URLs with a 'Content-Type: application/json' response header. It shouldn’t be, because the contents aren’t JSON—they’re instead executable JSONP IIFE JavaScript. And your browser’s refusing to execute it because it’s also served with a 'X-Content-Type: nosniff' header. The fix is: `https://api.soundcloud.com/` should instead be serving those with a 'Content-Type: text/javascript' header. There’s otherwise no way to fix this on your side in your frontend code. Soundcloud needs to fix it.